# Is editorializing about something off-topic an issue of moderation?

Tags: discussion, answers, scope

Recently on the Music site we had [this answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/5393/28) posted to a question asking about sheet music resources.  (I don't think the question is a good one, but ignore that for the moment.)  The answer did answer the question, providing two sites with a decent description.

However, the bulk of the answer is editorializing on the legality of sheet music sites, copyright, and so on.  [The current policy](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/43/28) is that legal issues are off-topic.  Asking a question that solicited this sort of discussion of legality would be off-topic.

I feel comfortable saying that editorializing answers are bad and should be downvoted, but they also seem to be a way to subvert the scope of the site as determined by the community.  As such, are they an issue of moderation?

- Is the answer also "off-topic"?  How do we distinguish between questions an answers in that regard?
- Should the answer be deleted?
- Should the answer be edited to remove the "off-topic" portion?  If edited back to its original form, should it be reverted and locked?
- Other?

Comment: I edited the post to remove the editorializing, but retained the basic point about the scores being in the public domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should the answer be edited to remove the "off-topic" portion? If edited back to its original form, should it be reverted and locked?

Seems perfectly reasonable to me. If the answers are good then keep them and if the opinion piece is bad then get rid of it.

Then knock off for a beverage of your choice.

Comment: I agree.  Edit the answer to remove the editorializing.  That's why we have community editing capabilities.